# Percentile must be in the range [0, 100]

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, scipy

The below shown code, is only a snippet of a big project that I am working one.

```
O = stats.scoreatpercentile(dfx[dfx['outlier'] == 1]['column_name'], np.abs(threshold))
l = stats.scoreatpercentile(dfx[dfx['outlier'] == 0]['column_name'], np.abs(threshold))
Data = stats.scoreatpercentile(dfx['column_name'], np.abs(threshold))
O, l, Data
```

Unfortunately, I am getting the following error

```
ValueError: percentile must be in the range [0, 100]
```

I have done some research but there wasn’t much help regarding this error

Comment: What is the value of `threshold` in your program?

Comment: @Guimoute, just checked it and turns out it is way bigger than 100, so now I am stuck and don't know how to over come this problem, considering that the threshold should stay like that

Comment: Then which percentile do you want? `100 * threshold / max value of your data` maybe?

Comment: Since your `threshold` can exceed 100--you say it can be as high as 6400 in a comment to an answer--I wonder if you are using the correct function.  Do you really understand what `scoreatpercentile` does?

Answer (score 2):

`scoreatpercentile`'s second argument should be within 0 and 100, so I'm guessing that for some values, `threshold` is under -100 or over 100.

This is because the mathematical meaning of the percentile, what is a 200 percentile? A possible 'solution' in this case is to map to 100 all values over it, you can do it like this:

```
def get_perc(threshold):
    perc = np.abs(threshold)
    return 100 if perc>100 else perc

O = stats.scoreatpercentile(dfx[dfx['outlier'] == 1]['column_name'], get_perc(threshold))
l = stats.scoreatpercentile(dfx[dfx['outlier'] == 0]['column_name'], get_perc(threshold))
Data = stats.scoreatpercentile(dfx['column_name'], get_perc(threshold))
O, l, Data
```

Before doing this, I'd recommend to clearify the concept of percentile and then you'll be able to decide if this is a good solution for you. I found [this article](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/percentiles.html) which explains it quite straightforward or you can check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile).

Comment: Is there a way to overpass this in case the theshold is bigger than 100 ?

Comment: This is more about the mathematical meaning of the percentile, what is a 200 percentile? I'll add one possible solution to my answer

Comment: @Gamopi, my threshold in this case is ```6400```, so way higher than ```100``` and in the future I might get different threshold that might be higher than this due to lots of data I am working with

Comment: maybe I am asking for too much but could you maybe implement your approach within my code ?

Answer (score 0):

second argument: np.abs(threshold) must be between 0 to 100. For more reference [this]:https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html can help